# MainForm.cs all messed up in VS 2010 C# on Windows 10?

Tags: c#

On my old main computer/ Win 7, I have VS C# 2010 working, and it displays my MainForm.cs project fine.

When I created my Main Windows 10 computer, I also installed VS C# 2010, and it also worked fine.  Now I have not used for a while, but needed today to make some changes to my code.  Then the MainForm.cs is all the wrong size, and as well all the fonts are twice the size they should be... all messed up.

I went back to the old computer, and the code is good there.

It is only on this Win. 10 machine, where the MainForm.cs is all messed up?

Comment: This question is off-topic for it isn't directly about programming. It looks like a software compatibility issue (old software new OS), most likely because that some old software doesn't show well on high DPI display. Try the new VS 2017/19, enjoy the best tool Microsoft has to offer.

Comment: Win10 gave lots of Winforms programmers a heart attack.  Its installer no longer selects 96 dpi (aka 100%) as the default monitor resolution.  So you get to see a problem that has existed for a long time, your form design is not dpiAware and would look messed up on any machine that did not use 96 dpi.  But VS is a dpiAware app so you get to see the messed-up look at design-time.  You could consider updating to the latest version of VS2017, it supports putting the designer in 96 dpi so it still looks like it did in the olden days.  Or put the monitor back to 100%.

Comment: Thanks... This only is happening in the Visual Studio App., as for the previous Programs I created they all run on any machine, and even this PC with the High-Resolution Monitor, no distortion. It is just the development software.  I will look into what you have explained.

Answer (score 1):

Installed VS 2019... Project Opened and It recognized the DPI problem. Allowed me to restart without the problem.  My project, which originally took 9 months to develop... works.  I thank you @kennyzx and @Hans Passant for your help!!!